# wsdl soap exception

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

Having trouble with soap exceptions.
I'm throwing soap exception in asp.net web service and have to somehow get that exception (in form of xml) to show in browser, like this:

```
SOAP 1.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring></faultstring>
<detail>
<Error>
<ErrorNumber>1</ErrorNumber>
<ErrorMessage>Error...</ErrorMessage>
</Error>
</detail>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Throwing exception from web service:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode detailNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, SoapException.DetailElementName.Name, SoapException.DetailElementName.Namespace);
XmlElement details = doc.CreateElement("Error");

XmlElement detailchild1 = doc.CreateElement("ErrorNumber");
detailchild1.InnerText = "1";
XmlElement detailchild2 = doc.CreateElement("ErrorMessage");
detailchild2.InnerText = "Error...";
details.AppendChild(detailchild1);
details.AppendChild(detailchild2);

detailNode.AppendChild(details);

throw new SoapException("Fault", SoapException.ClientFaultCode, "", details);
```

If I test it with windows application that calls that service, I can catch exception and extract all details so it seems that everything works with creating xml and throwing exception.
But all I'm getting from browser is internal error 500, which is according to other answers I found normal behaviour. Can I somehow get that xml in browser instead of internal error 500, maybe by changing web.config, IIS settings...

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this

```
throw new SoapException("Fault", SoapException.ClientFaultCode, "", details);
```

be

```
throw new SoapException("Fault", SoapException.ClientFaultCode, "", detailNode);
```

?